# Adding new settings to NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I use `NSUserDefaults` to store some app settings.

I need to set some default value to my settings.

So I added `isAppFirstLaunch` value to defaults and set all needed default(initial) values to my settings in on app first launch.

But very often i add some new settings. In that case `isAppFirstLaunch is FALSE` and i can't set any default value to it so i have to delete my app and install it againg.

So the question is: *How to set new settings default values?*.

---

As i unserstand if my app is in the appstore

```
[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary]objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"]];
```

than i can store app version in my defaults and check if version changed set new defaults.

But what to do with debugging? Should i always delete the app to clean defualts?

Comment: This is exactly what [`-[NSUserDefaults registerDefaults:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/registerDefaults:) is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just check whether the setting already exists (if different than NULL) and if it doesn't exist, set it to the default value.

You can add a code to your app delegate's `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method that checks if the setting is NULL and is so, than it sets it. Do this for every setting in the app.

Comment: Nice answer, i also thought about that as i check the app first launch. But all the default values are int, bool and float. That is why floatForKey: or boolForKey: wouldn't return me NULL.

Comment: Well than it would return nil

Comment: @george it will return nil for these types

Comment: @george and you can just check if it is empty or not

Comment: I mean that floatForKey should return float, how could it return nil

Comment: It wouldn't but it would return an empty float, so check for that. Also you can use NSFloat for the settings and then it would return NULL

Comment: How exactly do you propose to check if a float is "empty"?

Comment: Also cannot understand

Comment: But as i understand i can store NSNumber with bool, float and int. And there check if nil